# Using InputStream with MultipartEntityBuilder : apache error

Tags: android, http, inputstream

I am using MultipartEntityBuilder and i want to send  image on server. I have image Uri. Image may be local or not, so i get input stream and send it this way:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
JSONObject result;
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ezduki.ru/api/content/add/image/");
InputStream iStream = con.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
multipartEntity.addTextBody("token", code);
multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("file", iStream);
httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
result = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

where con is  my main activity context (code runs in AsyncTask).
I am trying to send local  file, and i get error from web server in result, here is log from web server:

[Fri Dec 13 10:01:03 2013] [error] [client 93.157.241.232] (70014)End of file found: mod_wsgi (pid=28449): Unable to get bucket brigade for request.
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error] ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /api/content/add/image/
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error]   File "/var/www/ezduki/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
.
.
.
packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 92, in _read_limited
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error]     result = self.stream.read(size)
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error] IOError: request data read error
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error] [client 93.157.241.232] mod_wsgi (pid=28709): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/ezduki/app/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Dec 13 15:01:03 2013] [error] [client 93.157.241.232] IOError: failed to write data

How must i  use MultipartEntityBuilder  and InputStream  together? Sending file like this

```
File f = new File(filePath);
multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(f));
```

works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

maybe you have already found out.
But I think you can use:

```
InputStream inputStream = ... ;
multipartEntity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(inputStream,"testFile.txt"))
```

Comment: You "think" one can use? Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: I have successfully used similar:
.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(byteFile,"filename.JPG"))

Answer (score 1):

if you send the file by stream,you just only can get the file  by InputStream of Request on server,i'm use the  dot net server,you can reference my code.

1,the client way

```
 for (File file : files) {
            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(file.getName(), file);
//            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file_a",file,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),file.getName());
//            multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("jpg",new FileBody(file));
        }
```

server  receive

```
 foreach (var key in files.AllKeys)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase hpf = files.Get(key);
.....
}
```

2,you want way  by stream

the client

```
 String boundary = creatBoundary();
        multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("no_name_file", is).setBoundary(boundary);
  HttpEntity he = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
        HttpPostHC4 httpPostHC4 = new HttpPostHC4(url);
        httpPostHC4.setEntity(he);
  httpPostHC4.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
        httpPostHC4.setHeader("IsStream","true");
```

receive server

```
     if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Any((key)=>key=="IsStream"))
                {
                    if(Request.Headers.Get("IsStream")=="true")
                    {
                        Models.File mf = new Models.File();
                        mf.Name = Request.Form.Get("file_name");
                        mf.Size = (int)Request.InputStream.Length;
                        if (Request.InputStream.CanRead)
                        {
                            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            string p = Path.Combine(Request.MapPath("UploadFiles"), Path.GetFileName(guid));
                            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(p,FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
                            }
                           }
                          }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not find direct solution. Do it this way know:

```
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addTextBody("token", code);

        InputStream iStream = con.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
        // saving temporary file
        String filePath = saveStreamTemp(iStream);
        File f = new File(filePath);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(f));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        result = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        f.delete();

String saveStreamTemp(InputStream fStream){
    final File file;
    try {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        file = new File(con.getCacheDir(), "temp_"+timeStamp + ".jpg");
        final OutputStream output;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        try {
            try {
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);

                output.flush();
            } finally {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            fStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

    return file.getPath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with MultiparEntity? See this code and try

```
             ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             attachImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, stream);
             byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();

             MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

             builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

             builder.addBinaryBody(bitmapNameParam, imageData, ContentType.create("image/png"), "photo.png");

             builder.addPart("oauth_token",  new StringBody("Your param", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

As you see below, attachImage is a bitmap and I transform in Bytes then i try to send a multipart to the server

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, using InputStream with MultipartEntityBuilder; inexplicable characters(eg:109d) appeared in the request body, which caused the upload of the file to fail：

```
POST /gcsa/web/personnel/pictureUpload.do HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
boundary=2ZYKoujgt0ExmEBwwwEOeB5cTXqjIiMKFrsr; charset=UTF-8
Host: 10.196.75.219:8664
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_181)
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Content-Length: 0

109d
--2ZYKoujgt0ExmEBwwwEOeB5cTXqjIiMKFrsr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageFile"; filename="wucheng1.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

There are no extra characters(eg:109d) above when using file,have you solved this problem?

Answer (score -1):

While sending images alone with text ,we should mention the file type..

Here is implementation

```
HttpClient htpclnt = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost(URL);

            try {

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);


                File imagefile = new File(SDcard full path);


                entity.addPart("caption", new StringBody("My image"));

                entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(imagefile ));


                hpost.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response = htpclnt.execute(hpost);
```

Comment: As I said, sending file works perfect. I am interested in using stream, because user can choose not local image in galery - and there is not real file path, its somewhere in google.
By the way, MultipartEntity  is deprecated. Use MultipartEntityBuilder