# Uploading a image from a local system( PC - file system ) to a server

Tags: android

### I am trying to put image for a imageview dynamically location from my desktop

---

**What i have done ?**

currently i am using the image from my drawable to POST the image to a server

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
```

---

**What i am trying to do ?**

- Now for the image view on click of image i should be able to select
  the image from my desktop(I am running my emulator)
- Images i need to select from `C:\images\` where all the sample images
  are located

***Note***:: Image location, I am not referring to SD card .... I am referring to a folder in my PC

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button submit;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    InputStream is;

    EditText name;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MainTest().execute();


            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Method to post the image to the server.
     * U will have to change the url which will accept the image data.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void postImageData() {


        try
        {

            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image); 

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:7002/Details/");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
                reqEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody(name.getText().toString()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
                reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
            }
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public class MainTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            postImageData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // data=jobj.toString();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.41"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Any ideas on achieving this

thanks

Comment: have you solved your problem or not?

Comment: check @LOG_TAG answer and follow first option

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this

1>Build your own server in your PC such that it load all images and image URI available for it, and make REST api for it retrieve all images from your pc to any place via JSON. such that image can be loaded in your mobile, can shared, uploaded any were.For example you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561478/using-inputstream-with-multipartentitybuilder-apache-error) method to upload the selected image.

2>Simple method:

Use [aFilechooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) librery in your project such that you can directly choose the image/file from the [3rd party apps](http://www.freewaregenius.com/five-ways-to-transfer-files-between-pc-and-android-wirelessly-including-some-that-youve-never-heard-of/) (ex:ES File Explorer)  which allow you to select the file from your pc and which allow to upload any file image from your pc to your server. only problem with this method is you have to view the images , files from other third party app! If want you can use google Drive sync mechanism to sync all image folder from your pc or [Use Google API](https://developers.google.com/drive/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public  int upLoad2Server(String pdid, String sourceFileUri, String imgtype) throws JSONException, IOException,MalformedURLException,FileNotFoundException {


    /**
     * create json object and pass into the webservice basic parameter
     */
    jsonObjAuth=new JSONObject();
    /*try {*/
        //jsonObjAuth.put("image", sourceFileUri);
        jsonObjAuth.put("user", UserInfo.username);
        jsonObjAuth.put("pass", UserInfo.userpass);
        jsonObjAuth.put("user_id", UserInfo.user_id);
        jsonObjAuth.put("patientid", UserInfo.user_id);
        jsonObjAuth.put("type", imgtype);
        jsonObjAuth.put("pdid", pdid);
    /*} catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    //webservice uri
    String upLoadServerUri =URLS.WS_BASE_URL+URLS.WS_ADD_IMAGE;

    // String [] string = sourceFileUri;
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    /*try {*/
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                                            // connection to
                                                            // the URL
        Log.i("URL_new","conn="+url+"="+conn);
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        // "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image";
        // filename=\"TypeA.png"\r\n"
        // String


        Log.i("data", "json " + jsonObjAuth.toString());
        //conn.setRequestProperty("data", jsonObjAuth.toString());

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""
                + imgtype + "\"" + lineEnd);

        Log.i("imgtype","filename:"+imgtype);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);




        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of
                                                        // maximum size
        Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ///////dharmesh

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        String json= jsonObjAuth.toString();
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n" + json + "\r\n");            
        //[myReturn appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n%@\r\n",[formKeys objectAtIndex:i],[myDictionary valueForKey:[formKeys objectAtIndex:i]]] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        ///////

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        //serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        //String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();



        // close streams
        Log.i("Upload file to server", fileName + " File is written");
        /*Log.i("Upload file to server", "HTTP Response is : "
                + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);*/
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    /*} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } */
    // this block will give the response of upload link
    /*try {*/
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("Huzza", "RES Message: " + line);
        }
        rd.close();
    /*} catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Huzza", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }*/
    return serverResponseCode; // like 200 (Ok)

} // end upLoad2Server
```

i hope its useful to you....if any query then please tell me about my code.